# 500 error while using .htaccess for a protected area

Tags: html

I am getting a 500 error while I am using `.htaccess` to protect a folder in my website.

what could be the problem? this is the code:

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile ....../.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `.htpasswd` file is three levels below the `.htaccess` file. then the `AuthUserFile` line should read

```
AuthUserFile ../../../.htpasswd
```